# Create array of array in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, arrayofarrays

I am trying to create an empty array of arrays in numpy, and add elements to it an a `for` loop.

I tried to create it by `arr_of_arrs = np.empty(num_of_arrays, dtype=np.array)`, but I got an error `TypeError: data type not understood`.

How can I do it?

Comment: `np.empty(num_of_arrays, dtype='object')`?

Comment: Do your arrays have a fixed type and fixed shape?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes. They are all arrays of numbers, and have the same length

Comment: `np.empty((num_of_arrays, len_of_array), dtype=np.float64)`.

Comment: But you could also just concatenate them all in one go: `np.array(arrays)`.